# How does return work in recursive?

Tags: php, recursion, return

Can we say that when `$number <2`  it doesn't call `factirial()` function again? Or it calls factorial() function but it always sets factorial to factorial(1). If so, I think recursive use more memory. Am I correct?

```
<?php function factorial($number){

                if ($number < 2) { 
                return 1; 
                } else { 
                return ($number * factorial($number-1)); 
                } 
            }

echo factorial(5);
?>
```

this is what I guess in the function

```
3*factorial(2)
2*factorial(1)
1*factorial(1)
1*factorial(1)
```

Comment: If `$number` < 2, the function returns and is not called again. The recursive state will only be entered when `$number` > 2.

Comment: why doesn't it always retun 1 because for any number it comes to `$number<2`

Comment: @BenM It will call itself when `$number >= 2` (minor typo)

Comment: You're passing in 5 in your sample, thus `$number - 1` > 2 (i.e. 4)

Comment: Recursive does take up more memory. Your function will likely cause PHP to die if you put in a large number like 10000.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we say that when $number <2 it doesn't call factirial() function again?

Yes